# Doma 2.0 の トランザクション　スコープ

Tags: java, orm

関数のロジックは複数メソッド間に散らばっている場合、トランサクションスコープはどうですか？

下記例を考慮、functionA のempDao更新処理と functionBのclassInfoDao更新処理は同一トランサクションですか？現在コーディングの条件は複数関数利用しないといけないので、なんかいい方法がありますか？

```
functionA() {
    TransactionManager tm = AppConfig.singleton().getTransactionManager();
    emp.setGroupNo("100");
    int updateResult = tm.required(() -> {
        return empDao.update(emp);
    };
    functionB(emp.getEmployeeNo(), emp.getGroupNo());
}

int functionB(String empNo, String groupNo) {
    TransactionManager tm = AppConfig.singleton().getTransactionManager();
    int updateResult = tm.required(() -> {
        int result = 0;
        List<ClassInfo> classList = classDao.selectById(empNo);
        for(ClassInfo class in classList) {
            class.setGroupNo(groupNo);
            result = classInfoDao.update(emp);
            if (result < 0) { break; }
        }
        return result;
    };
    return updateResult;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

少しコードを変更していますが、次のように`TransactionManager#tm.required`に渡すラムダ式の中から`functionB`を呼び出すのであれば、`functionA`の`empDao`更新処理と`functionB`の`classInfoDao`更新処理は同じトランザクションで処理されます。

```
void functionA() {
    TransactionManager tm = AppConfig.singleton().getTransactionManager();
    emp.setGroupNo("100");
    tm.required(() -> {
        empDao.update(emp);
        functionB(emp.getEmployeeNo(), emp.getGroupNo());
    });
}
```

Comment: @Nakamuraさん、 functionBの中で、tm.requiredは呼ばなくてもいいですか？

Comment: 呼んでも呼ばなくてもどちらでも良いです。tm.requiredはすでにトランザクションが存在すればそちらのトランザクションに参加するからです。functionB単独で利用する場合にトランザクションが必要であれば呼ぶのが良いと思います。

Comment: トランサクションマネージャはsingletonなので、マルチ・スレッドの環境（例えばウェブ・アプリ）で同時トランサクションブラックを利用場合、トランサクションが打つかる可能性がありますか？

Comment: トランザクションマネージャーの中ではThreadLocalを使ってトランザクションを制御しています。したがって、複数スレッドで競合することはありません。